# How should be a required cell in table be designed?

Tags: tables, data-tables

I am currently making a design for tables that are editable and one of the requirement from the stakeholders is that there should be a required cell to be filled out. Just seeking an advice on how should this be done? Should I put an asterisk on the table as a sign that it is a required field or should I just color the cell red whenever the user saves their data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't use a table**

It's as simple as that.

You're wondering this because this behavior doesn't exist (at least I've never seen it). The usual way is to use a form to enter the content and then use a table to display the information you enter into the form. And of course, when you use a form, you can use its features and affordances, including asterisks for required fields